# Laravel - Pass String Parameter from View to Controller

Tags: laravel

I have these tables:

```
users (User): username,plan
billings: (Billings): email,amount,plan
```

The issue I have is that in users table, plan is interger (1=daily, 2=Weekly, 3=monthly) while in billings table, plan is varchar(daily, weekly,monthly).I have created billing controller and view using the Billings Model. I want to relate the two fields.

This is the working code that creates billing:

**Controller**

```
public function usersBilling()
{
    $billings = DB::table("billings")
        ->select("billings.plan", DB::raw("COUNT(billings.plan) as total_plans") ,DB::raw("SUM(billings.amount) as total_amount"))
        ->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
        ->groupBy("billings.plan")
        ->orderByRaw('billings.plan ASC')
        ->paginate(15);

    return view('report.usersBilling', compact('billings'));        
}
```

**report/usersBilling.blade.php**

```
<td><a href="{{ route('report.showBillingDetail',$billing->plan) }}">{{ $billing->plan }}</a></td>               
<td>{{ $billing->total_plans }}</td>
<td>{{ $billing->total_amount }}</td>
```

Here is the Controller I want to complete

```
public function showBillingDetail(Request $request,$billingtype)
{
    $user= User::findOrFail($billingtype);

    return view('report.showBillingDetail', compact('user'));
}
```

I want to complete this.

When I click on the plan through the link in:

```
href="{{ route('report.showBillingDetail',$billing->plan) }}"
```

It should display all users with that plan. Since plan in users table is integer (1,2,3) and plan in billings is varchar (daily, weekly, monthly), how do I write a query in the UserController that will receive the plan parameter from the billing view and relate it with plan in users table and select all fields in the users table based on the parameter. `1=daily`, `2=weekly`, `3=monthly`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you have to use Eloquent Model to query on database. It will provide you flexibility to manage these types of cases.

But if you are preferring `DB::table()` then you can add one more select field which will identify you plan like `daily`, `weekly` or `monthly`.

```
public function usersBilling()
{
    $billings = DB::table("billings")
        ->select("billings.plan", DB::raw("COUNT(billings.plan) as total_plans") ,DB::raw("SUM(billings.amount) as total_amount", DB::raw("IF(billings.plan == 1), 'daily", IF(billings.plan == 2), 'weekly', 'monthly')))
        ->join("users","users.email","=","billings.email")
        ->groupBy("billings.plan")
        ->orderByRaw('billings.plan ASC')
        ->paginate(15);

    return view('report.usersBilling', compact('billings'));        
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand me. The controller you touched is working fine. I only showed it as the one that displayed the view where the parameter will the passed.  I want to pass the parameter from that view to this controller and I dont know how to perfect other query.     >public function showBillingDetail